# How to check different conditions in a data frame based on the values in another data frame?

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, subset

UPDATED:

I have two data frames (df1 and df2) as you can see in the tables below.
Based on the conditions in df1, I need to check the values in df2. The expected output is also presented.
The condition is based on the columns `dep` and `value` in `df1` checked in `df2` against the the variables taken from the column `var` in `df1`. Please see the following examples:

For instance, based on row 1 in df1, we judge whether the values in column A in df2 are TRUE or FALSE.

1. `if E == 1, A == TRUE`
2. `if E != 1`, we need to check the following conditions:

   `- if A == NA, A == TRUE`

   `- if A == any values other than NA, A == FALSE`
3. `If A and E are both NAs, A == TRUE`

similarly, for row 3 in df1 it would be:

1. `if A != 0, C == TRUE`
2. `if A == 0`, we need to check the value of C based on the following conditions:

   `- if C == NA, C == TRUE`

   `- if C == any values other than NA, C == FALSE`
3. `If A and C are both NAs, C == TRUE`

Besides, in df1, when `value` == `NA`, we do not need to do anything (these rows can be removed).

Importantly, in my real df2, the variables belong to various classes and are not just integer/numeric.

I am all eyes to read your advice.

df1:

```
| var  |value| dep  |
|---   |---- | ---- |
| A    |==1  |  E   |
| B    |==1  |  E   |
| C    |!=0  |  A   |
| D    |==2  |  G   |
| E    |NA   |  NA  |
| F    |NA   |  NA  |
| G    |NA   |  NA  |
```

df2:

```
| ID  | B  | G  | A   |C   |D  |E  |
|---  |--- | ---| --  |--- |---|---|
| 1q  | 1  | NA | 0   | NA | NA| 2 |
| 2d  | 1  |  3 | 0   | 1  | 1 | 2 |
| 4f  | NA | NA | 1   | 1  | 1 | 1 |
| 3g  | 1  | 2  | 1   | NA | 1 | NA|
| 8j  | 2  | 2  | 1   | NA | 1 | NA|
| 5g  | NA | NA | NA  | 1  | 3 | 3 |
| 9l  | 1  | NA | NA  | 1  | 2 |NA |
```

Desired output would be:

```
| ID  | B  |  A | C |D  |
|---  |--- | ---|---|---|
| 1q  | F  | F  | T | T |
| 2d  | F  | F  | F | F | 
| 4f  | T  | T  | T | F | 
| 3g  | F  | F  | T | T | 
| 8j  | F  | F  | T | T | 
| 5g  | T  | T  | T | F | 
| 9l  | T  | T  | T | F |
```

Comment: Can you include the desired output for your example please?

Comment: for example, row `1q`:  Variable `B`, `==1`, `TRUE`.  Variable `G`,`NA`, no action. `A`, `==1`, `FALSE`. `Q`, not in df1?, no action?.  `C`, `!=0`, unclear - NA is not 0, but there are no 0 values in the table.  should this be considered `TRUE` or `FALSE`?  `D`, `==2`, `FALSE`, `E`, `NA`, no action - what is the summary of these comparisons?  One value, or seven?

Comment: in general, problems of the type, I want to do things to data.frame `A` based on entries in data.frame `B` should be solved by joining the data to have a dataframe `A/B` and then process that conditionally. Are you familiar with joins ?

Comment: (1) What happened to `G` and `E`? (2) The last two resulting values for `A` are true but for the last two values of `E`, only one is `==1`. Is your desired output correct? If so, please explain the exceptions and other rules/logic you may have to consider here.

Comment: Please correct me where I'm misunderstand this circuitous problem: in `df2` you have a column named `A`. We reference `df1` for this and see that where `var` is `"A"`, we see the `dep` variable is `E` and the `value` is `==1`. So now we go to `df2` and see that `df2$E`'s last two values are 3 and 1. Where is this being lost?

Comment: @r2evans the conditions would be TRUE if in df2 1)  when `E != 1` (opposite of what is stated in value column in df1), A equals NA or 2) when `E == 1`, any value in A is TRUE.. Because the last value in E equals 1, any value including NA in A is considered True. And in the row before that, `E == 3`, so it meets the condition (`E !=1`). So it means that A should equal NA. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: No it is not clear. The last two values of `E` are different. The last two values of `A` in `df2` are the same. In the output, the last two values of `A` are the same. By your logic they should not be.

Comment: @r2evans Let me put it this way: We first check column E and see if the values equal 1 or not. for ID 5g, `E!=1`. Great! Now we expect the corresponding value in A to be NA. And it is NA. so TRUE!  For ID 9l, the value in `E ==1`, so no need to even check what is in column A, because any value would be TRUE. This is why we are T for both rows in column A.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Wow, this is ... really circuitous. May I ask what you are really working with where a column's non-NA value means nothing to it but perhaps to another column?

Comment: By your logic, looking at `C` (comparing `A` with `!=0`): both of 5g and 9l have `A` as NA, so therefore they should be false, which is not correct in your output. So if that's correct, then looking at `A` (`E` and `==1`), when `E` is NA (3g and 8j)  we should not have false but we do. Do you really have _so many rules_ (in `df1`) that it is onerous to fix the data rule-by-rule? This would be far simpler with actual code (and, admittedly, unambiguous rules and sample data/output).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here F is character variable, and G is modified based on it

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)
library(glue)
rules_1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~var, ~value,    ~dep,
  "A",   "==1",    "E", 
  "B",   "==1",    "E", 
  "C",   "!=0",    "A", 
  "D",   "==2",    "G", 
  "E",      NA,     NA, 
  "F",      NA,     NA, 
  "G",    "%in% c('b','d')",     "F",
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  ID = c("1q", "2d", "4f", "3g", "8j", "5g", "9l"),
  B = c(1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L),
  G = c(3L, 3L, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, NA),
  A = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA),
  C = c(NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L),
  D = c(NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L),
  E = c(2L, 2L, 1L, NA, NA, 3L, 1L),
  F = letters[1:7]
)

# And for variables that have NA values in df1, we do not need to do anything. 

(rules_2 <- filter(rules_1,
                   !is.na(dep)))

# rules from data
(rules_3 <- mutate(rules_2,
                   rule = glue("case_when({dep}{value}~TRUE,is.na({var})~TRUE,TRUE ~ FALSE)")))

(mutators <- rules_3$rule)
names(mutators) <- rules_3$var

(parsed_mutators <- rlang::parse_exprs(mutators))

mutate(df2,
       !!!parsed_mutators)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Could you please explain this: `case_when({dep}{value}~TRUE,is.na({var})~TRUE,TRUE ~ FALSE)"`? Having variables in curly brackets is new to me.

Comment: It'd the syntax for glue. Check the glue docs/vignette

Comment: The original problem statement involves rules over numeric variables. So don't expect it to work on a different class

Comment: By the way, I really liked your approach. You simplified the conditions really in a smart way.

Comment: as a matter of fact, this approach would work on character variables with character based rules ; I'll edit my answer to demonstrate that. Therefore if you have other problems; you will need to find a way to reproduce them and ask a question with context given

Comment: Oh I see I had made a mistake in applying your code to my data. But I still could not get the output because some of my variables (i.e., `var`)are weirdly named like this: D#XX (di). So I made the following change and it works! `case_when({dep}{value}~TRUE,is.na({glue::double_quote (var)})~TRUE,TRUE ~ FALSE)`. Indebted to you for your help.

Comment: I just discovered a new condition in my data! When both `var` and `dep` are NAs in df2, it is TRUE! Can this condition be incorporated in this code?

Comment: May I ask you for some more help with this code? I really need it.

Comment: If you have a new issue, I will look at a new post you make to describe it

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I just posted a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)


dcast(
  melt(df2, "ID")[df1, on=.(variable=dep)][!is.na(value)][, t:=eval(parse(text=paste0(value,i.value))), .(ID,var)],
  ID~var, value.var="t",fill = F
)
```

Output:

```
       ID      A      B      C      D
   <char> <lgcl> <lgcl> <lgcl> <lgcl>
1:     1q  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
2:     2d  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
3:     3g  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE
4:     4f   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE
5:     5g  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
6:     8j  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE
7:     9l   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
```

Here is a `dplyr/tidyr` version:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

inner_join(pivot_longer(df2,-ID), df1, by=c("name"="dep"), multiple="all") %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value.x)) %>% 
  reframe(t = eval(parse(text = paste0(value.x, value.y))), .by=c(ID,var)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = var,values_from=t,values_fill = F,names_sort = T) %>% 
  arrange(ID)
```

Either your desired output is incorrect, or I didn't understand the question correclty.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated the question and now it is much more clear. May I ask you to kindly read it again? I really need it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your data.frame `df1` (*note the separate column for comparator and value*):

```
df1 <- data.frame(var = LETTERS[1:7],
                  operator = c('==', '==', '!=', '==', rep(NA, 3)),
                  value = c(1, 1, 0, 2, rep(NA, 3)),
                  dep = c(unlist(strsplit('EEAG', '')), rep(NA, 3))
                  )
```

```
  var operator value  dep
1   A       ==     1    E
2   B       ==     1    E
3   C       !=     0    A
4   D       ==     2    G
5   E     <NA>    NA <NA>
6   F     <NA>    NA <NA>
```

... and this df2:

```
df2 <- 
structure(list(ID = c("1q", "2d", "4f", "3g", "8j", "5g", "9l"
), B = c(1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L), G = c(3L, 3L, NA, 2L, 2L, 
NA, NA), A = c(NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA), Q = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1L, 1L), C = c(NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L), D = c(NA, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L), E = c(2L, 2L, 1L, NA, NA, 3L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
7L))
```

```
> df2
  ID  B  G  A  Q  C  D  E
1 1q  1  3 NA NA NA NA  2
2 2d  1  3 NA NA  1  1  2
3 4f NA NA  1 NA  1  1  1
4 3g  1  2  1 NA NA  1 NA
5 8j  2  2  1 NA NA  1 NA
6 5g NA NA NA  1  1  3  3
7 9l  1 NA NA  1  1  2  1
```

... you could set up a condition list like this:

```
library(dplyr)

condition_list <- 
  df1 |>
  filter(complete.cases(operator, dep)) |>
  distinct() |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(condition = list(c(x = var, operator = operator, y = value))) |>
  pull(condition, dep)
```

... to scan the columns of df2 with the corresponding item of the condition list like so:

```
names(condition_list) |>
  lapply(\(col_name){
    cond = condition_list[[col_name]]
    xs <- do.call(cond['operator'],
                  args = list(df2[[cond['x']]], ## df2 column to test
                              cond['y']) ## value to test against
                  )
    xs[is.na(xs)]  <- FALSE
    xs
  }
  ) |>
  setNames(names(condition_list)) |>
  list2DF()
```

```
      A     B     C     D
1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
2 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
4 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
5 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
6 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
7  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Please indicate which values in the output of my solution should be different, and why. Based on your description, `A` should contain the results of `E == 1`, or, if `is.na(E)`, A should be `FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I admit the conditions are really weird. But here is the point you are missing: When the results of `E == 1` are not met in A, there are two conditions: `TRUE` If `A == NA`, `FLASE` if `A == any values other than NA`. So in df2, in rows 1, 2 and 6, A should equal TRUE because `E!= 1` and `A == NA`. I hope it is a bit more clear now.

Comment: While you now require A to be `c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)` at positions 1, 2 and 6, it is `c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)` at these positions in what you present as "desired output" in your original question. There's been quite some suggestions by other community members already, so I suggest you tweak one of those or mine until it suits your actual intent.

Comment: You are right. This is because you are using a different df than what is presented in the question. The desired output I mentioned concerns the df you are using.